# QChartView QLineSeries select by mouse click

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcharts, qchartview

Unfortunately, I can't find any way to catch a signal of mouse click on any `QLineSeries` at `QChartView`. This is required for the subsequent increase in the thickness of the curve on the graph.

Comment: use https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qxyseries.html#clicked

Comment: It's need to access specific series on chart by mouse click to modify that line. What should I do?

Comment: you could explain yourself better and provide a [mcve] and read [ask]

Comment: QChartView does not have any clicked signal, where did you get that information from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the clicked signal of the `QLineSeries` and since it will affect the same series then you could create a derived class

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QChartView>
#include <QLineSeries>
#include <random>

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

class LineSeries: public QLineSeries{
public:
    LineSeries(QObject *parent = nullptr):
        QLineSeries(parent)
    {
        connect(this, &QXYSeries::clicked, this, &LineSeries::onClicked);
    }
private slots:
    void onClicked(){
        QPen p = pen();
        p.setWidth(p.width()+1);
        setPen(p);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->legend()->hide();

    chart->setTitle("Simple line chart example");

    std::random_device rd;     // only used once to initialise (seed) engine
    std::mt19937 rng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uni(0, 10);

    for(size_t i=0; i< 5; i++){
        LineSeries *series = new LineSeries();
        for(size_t j=0; j < 10; j++){
            *series << QPointF(j, uni(rng));
        }
        chart->addSeries(series);
    }
    chart->createDefaultAxes();

    QChartView chartView(chart);
    chartView.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    chartView.resize(640, 480);
    chartView.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

Update:

you have to connect the series, you do not understand that it is ui-> vchrt but assume that it is a QChartView, but QChartView does not have the clicked signal so it seems strange to me that this code works, on the other hand:

```
QLineSeries **series;
series = new QLineSeries*[data.size()];
```

is a bad practice in C ++, you are using the C style in C ++, you should use container as QList , for example:

```
QList<QLineSeries *> series;

for(size_t i=0; i< data.size(); i++){
    QLineSeries *serie = new QLineSeries();
    for(size_t j=0; j < 10; j++){
        *serie << QPointF(/*values*/);
    }
    series << serie;
    connect(serie, &QXYSeries::clicked, this, &MainWindow::on_series_Clicked);
    chart->addSeries(serie);
}
```

after that you must modify your slot, only the `QObject`s are passed the pointer, `QPointF` must be passed by value, but even so it is not necessary since you will not use that data, and as the one that emits the signal is the `QLineSeries` this is passed through `sender()` in the slot, with a casting we get the series and the changes are made.:

***.h**

```
private slots:
    void on_series_Clicked();
```

***.cpp**

```
void MainWindow::on_series_Clicked(){
    auto serie = qobject_cast<QLineSeries *>(sender());
    QPen p = serie->pen();
    p.setWidth( p.width() == 1 ? 5: 1);
    serie->setPen(p);
}
```

Comment: And now your own class LineSeries is no longer needed? Is on_series_Clicked() slot a member of MainWindow class?

Comment: @JohnySins 
my own class is no longer needed, on_series_Clicked if it is a MainWindow slot.

Comment: Thanks, @eyllanesc. How can I get serie index in container for more complex behavior of on_series_Clicked() slot?

Comment: @JohnySins use [indexOf()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#indexOf) method: `int index = your_containter.indexOf(your_serie)`,

Comment: @JohnySins  if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, but you know do it review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.